# Hibernate Criteria does not work in SQLite

Tags: hibernate, sqlite

My gear:

- Hibernate 3.6.9
- Hibernate SQLite Dialect from http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-sqlite/

My entity class is simple,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RegistrationRequests")
public class RegistrationRequest {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Integer id;
    String uuid;
    ... getters and setters ...
}
```

uuid is assigned to UUID.randomUUID().toString(), and correctly persisted in database.
Now, the issue is when I try to retrieve stored request from database, using Hibernate Criteria.

```
   Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(RegistrationRequest.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("uuid", '\'' + uuid + '\''));
    List requests = criteria.list();
```

always yields an empty result, however if I execute generated SQL,

```
select
        this_.id as id2_0_,
        this_.created as created2_0_,
        this_.email as email2_0_,
        this_.isVerified as isVerified2_0_,
        this_.name as name2_0_,
        this_.password as password2_0_,
        this_.surname as surname2_0_,
        this_.uuid as uuid2_0_ 
    from
        RegistrationRequests this_ 
    where
        this_.uuid='ced61d13-f5a7-4c7e-a047-dd6f066d8e67'
```

result is correct (that is one record is selected from database).

I am kind of stumped, tried everything with no results...

Comment: The `'\'' + uuid + '\''` looks strange. What happens if you use uuid without the ' arround the uuid?

Answer (score 1):

you dont have to set the where clause value yourself as far as I am aware about hibernate api (I use Nhibernate), thus when you set your where clause value as 'myValue', you are actually searching for string to match 'myValue' where as you want o search for myValue.

Changing to this should hopefully get it working:

```
Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(RegistrationRequest.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("uuid", uuid));
    List requests = criteria.list();
```

Comment: That does not help much, since SQLite can't handle queries with hyphens, so I need to quote the parameter. Without quotes SQLite complains:
Error: unrecognized token: "4c7e"

Comment: what is the query that is generated when you have the above criteria query?

Comment: The query is exactly as in my post, only without quotes around uuid. When I try to execute this statement, I got SQLIte complaining about unrecognized token.
I think that this might be a SQLite specific issue...